# Marginal distribution for the off-diagonal elements of a Matrix following an Inverse-Wishart

Tags: multivariate-analysis, marginal-distribution, wishart-distribution

I've found on CV the marginal distribution for the main-diagonal elements of a matrix which follows an Inverse-Wishart distribution.

However, what will happen to the off-diagonal elements? what marginal distribution will they follow?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10006/marginal-distribution-of-the-diagonal-of-an-inverse-wishart-distributed-matrix for the main diagonal